# p4 integ: File(s) not in client view

Tags: perforce

I am trying to create a branch but keep getting:

> File(s) not in client view.

error.

I am running this command:

```
p4 integ //depot/trunk/... //depot/branches/branchA/...
```

Not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: The error message references your client view, so that might be a good place to start.  Run "p4 client" -- is //depot/branches/branchA/... (or a superset thereof) mapped in your client view?

Comment: yes that was it, thanks Sam!

Answer (score 3):

In order to open files for branch, they need to be in your client view -- the "file(s) not in client view" error means they are not.

An alternate way to create a branch that does not require the files to be in your client view is the "p4 populate" command (which skips the usual workflow of open/submit and just creates the files instantaneously):

```
p4 populate -d "Creating branchA." //depot/trunk/... //depot/branches/branchA/...
```

Note that you will not be able to actually do much with this branch after it's been created (e.g. sync it, edit the files in it, etc) if it's not in your client view, so you'll probably want to add it to your view either way.